# python script for downloading all Ctrl+Alt+Del webcomics?

Tags: python, download, web-scraping

Does anyone have one? Ive tried Comicdownloader but that only lets me download the newest comic and I dont understand Python well enough to figure out how to change it to download all the comics

Comment: I think the cad tag is for computer aided design, not Ctrl+Alt+Del comics ;)

Comment: Please provide some more details: URLs to the comic site, and how much do you know python.

Comment: Does it have to be a python script doing it?

Comment: Does it have to be Ctrl+Alt+Del?

Comment: *cough* *cough* thepiratebay *cough* *cough* mininova *cough*

Comment: I would prefer it to be python and I do know that there is a program on Mininova and Thepiratebay that does the same job but I would prefer to have the cod. I know hardly anything about python just how to find and run certain commands usually taken from premade python scripts and the link to the website is http://www.cad-comic.com

Comment: sorry for the double post but I found this Explosm script and thought maybe someone could modify it for Ctrl Alt Del. I have tried and failed. Here is the link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394978/download-from-explosm-net-comics-script-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not python and the method is not very elegant either but it'll work.

After a brief inspection of the [ctrl+alt+del archive site](http://www.ctrlaltdel-online.com/archives.php?b=c) I found that all the comics are stored in /comics/ as jpg files.

With that assumption, running the following command in a shell on a *nix machine will download all comics. The filenames are obviously dates in the format YYYYMMDD.

```
$ for filename in $(seq 20020101 20090726); do wget http://www.ctrlaltdel-online.com/comics/"$filename".jpg; done
```

Oh, and it may take a while : ).

Comment: +1 since the OP credited your solution w/out accepting your answer.

Comment: you can do this with curl: 

`curl http://ctrlaltdel-online.com/comics[20020101..20090726].jpg` 

This has the advantage that only one connection is made to the server, while your solution may be blocked and considered as a spammer spider. 

man curl for more details.

Comment: dalloliogm: I tried your solution directly but I get an error. Then I tried it with "-" (as it says in the man) instead of ".." which will just fetch me a lot of HTML (index.html i guess). You may be right about the spammer spider though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several approaches. You could look at the urls of the comic images themselves, to see if they follow a pattern, write a small script to generate urls that match the pattern, and simply use wget or something similar to download them. To learn the requisite python, I recommend the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/). Look specifically at ways of combining strings, string formatting, string operations, so you can build your URLs from component strings, numbers, and so forth. This sort of project may be a good excuse to learn python, which will probably help you with other things in the future. (and is FUN!)

Alternatively, I imagine that people have done this before - there almost certainly are apps out there that do what you want, given the urls of the images, or just the pattern of urls. Have a look around.

You could write to the author of the comic and ask if they are available in bulk somehow, possibly for purchase, maybe as a book. I imagine ctrl-alt-del is popular enough to simply absorb the added load of you downloading the entire archive, but smaller websites might not appreciate it - though I don't think they can really stop you or anything.

As for your question, this site should help you with your programming questions, help you with problems you're having, nudge you along the way - but mostly people don't appreciate it if you ask them to just write your code for you. Learn some python, try it yourself, if you run into any problems, ask then.

Answer (score 0):

I use urllib with a modified user-agent(since Timmy blocked the original) and BeautifulSoup.
Anyway, heres the date generator:

```
t1 = datetime.date(2002, 10, 22)
t2 = datetime.date.today()
while t2 > t1:
    t1 = t1 + datetime.date.resolution
    toon = t1.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    url1 = str(toon)
    main(url1)
```

and my main(): looks like this (took the "Check if file exists" part out)

```
def main(url):
    con = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.cad-comic.com")
    con.request("GET", "/cad/" + url)
    r1 = con.getresponse()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r1)
    img = soup.findAll("img")[1]
    nImg = str(img)
    imgSplit = re.split('"', nImg)
    imgUrl = imgSplit[1]
    if imgUrl.startswith('http://www.cad-comic.com/comics/'):
        MeOpans().retrieve(imgUrl, url + ".jpg")
        print "Downloaded " + url
```

"MeOpans()" looks like this:

```
class MeOpans(urllib.URLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
```

Comment: If the owner of the content blocked your user agent, *maybe* it's because he doesn't want you scraping his content....